# C++: Local reference variable value based on a condition

Tags: c++, reference

I was thinking about what is the use of local variable which have been declared as reference type. I found it useless because everywhere I use a ref variable I can pretty well use just the variable the reference I assigned to. Until I realized that a ref variable may reference a variable which is hard to compute.

So I "invented" that code:

```
system::path& pathSeparator;

if( system::is_mswindows() ) {
    pathSeparator = long::namespace::access::path::mswindows::pathSeparator;
} else {
    pathSeparator = long::namespace::access::path::posix::pathSeparator;
}

/* code which uses pathSeparator a lot */
```

but I get an error because `pathSeparator` is not assigned a value during its initialization in the first line of example code. If I do the same with `pathSeparator` declared as a pointer then it works fine, but now I'm forced to dereference the variable every time I use it.

So, is it possible to use a reference variable which reference is based on a condition, for a code that uses the variable a lot (as so to not write if-s every time the code needs its value)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either use a conditional operator:

```
system::path& pathSeparator = system::is_mswindows()
    ? long::namespace::access::path::mswindows::pathSeparator
    : long::namespace::access::path::posix::pathSeparator;
```

... or, if you need more room, an immediately-invoked lambda:

```
auto& pathSeparator = [&]() -> system::path& {
    if( system::is_mswindows() ) {
        return long::namespace::access::path::mswindows::pathSeparator;
    } else {
        return long::namespace::access::path::posix::pathSeparator;
    }
}();
```

Comment: For a while I was thinking about the ternary operator, but your answer with lambda surprised me :) .